# Properties about the Generalized Hermite-type polynomial sequence $f_n(x)=e^{-p(x)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{p(x)}$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonal-polynomials

Suppose we have the Generalized Hermite-type polynomial sequences $f_n(x)=e^{-p(x)}\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{p(x)}$ , where $p(x)$ is any polynomials of degree at least $2$ .

$1.$ Do these polynomial sequences satisfy any homogeneous linear ODE of polynomial coefficients? Find the one of minimal order if this is the case.

$2.$ Are these polynomial sequences orthogonal, especially when $p(x)$ are polynomials of degree more than $2$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I want the linear ODEs should be homogeneous ones rather than that of inhomogeneous ones, so I modified the question.